# Tried many suggestions, how do I install mysql2 gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to install a mysql2 gem on a ruby on rails app. I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.04 and this is the error I get when I run `sudo gem install mysql2` or `bundle install`:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing  -g -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c client.c
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing  -g -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c mysql2_ext.c
./client.h:16:1: warning: ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’ defined but not used
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing  -g -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c result.c
gcc -shared -o mysql2.so client.o mysql2_ext.o result.o -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu    -lruby1.8 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I've tried installing with mysql_config, I've installed the libmysqlclient-dev and libmysql-ruby libraries, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql. None of it works. I am able to successfully install mysql gem but not mysql2.

I'm running ruby1.8 and Rails 2.3.5. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby

sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

sudo gem install mysql2

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [blog](http://blog.trevorbramble.com/past/2011/5/25/installing_the_mysql2_ruby_gem_on_ubuntu_1104/) and others like it.  But ultimately, I recommend upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10.  I experienced many strange errors when running 11.04, since moving to 11.10 everything is much more stable.

Comment: Did you get a chance to upgrade?  If so, how did that help you?

Comment: I had to work on a different project so I actually didn't get a chance to test this. When I get back around to it, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running CentOS/Redhat, try install the following packages (using yum):

```
MySQL-devel-5.5.22-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.5.22-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.22-2.el6.x86_64
```